# Highlight R Code Syntax in Wordpress

Tags: r, wordpress, syntax, syntax-highlighting

I would like to highlight R syntax in a wordpress blog, so that it looks similar as in RStudio. I found the [wp-synthax-plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-syntax/), which is able to highlight R code as follows:

[image]

However, the colors are in my opinion way too extreme and I am searching for something more similar to basic RStudio. The code should be highlighted as follows:

[image]

**Question: Is there a plugin for wordpress that produces such code or is there a way how to customize the colors myself?**

Comment: check out https://www.r-statistics.com/2010/09/r-syntax-highlighting-for-bloggers-on-wordpress-com/

Comment: @chinsoon12 I saw this blog post already, but unfortunately it produces very colorful code as well.

Comment: i htink trimming the number of elements in `this.regexList` in shBrushR.js would reduce the number of words being flagged out for coloring. i.e. you can just keep the css only for comments and constants

Comment: @chinsoon12 Thanks for your comments! Iam new to wordpress. Could you please elaborate what you meant with " trimming the number of elements in this.regexList in shBrushR.js"?

Comment: i have never used wp. you might need to follow this closely https://yihui.name/en/2010/09/syntaxhighlighter-brush-for-the-r-language/ ... i will post an example of the shBrushR.js

Comment: I use [prism](https://nextgenthemes.com/plugins/prism-syntax-highlighter-for-wordpress/) on my blog (https://rud.is/b/) and it has highly customizable syntax CSS. I had used the same syntax one you mentioned. Prism is lightweight and far more robust, is updated when there are issues — including security issues — and lets you organize R code as well. Unfortunately, this is also an off-topic question and likely to (eventually) be closed.

Comment: @hrbrmstr Thanks for the hint. prism looks interesting, I might change if I continue to have problems with wp-synthax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Original shBrushR.js

```
/**
*  Author: Yihui Xie
*  URL: http://yihui.name/en/2010/09/syntaxhighlighter-brush-for-the-r-language
*  License: GPL-2 | GPL-3
*/
SyntaxHighlighter.brushes.R = function() {
    var keywords = 'if else repeat while function for in next break TRUE FALSE NULL Inf NaN NA NA_integer_ NA_real_ NA_complex_ NA_character_';
    var constants = 'LETTERS letters month.abb month.name pi';
    this.regexList = [
    { regex: SyntaxHighlighter.regexLib.singleLinePerlComments, css: 'comments' },
    { regex: SyntaxHighlighter.regexLib.singleQuotedString,    css: 'string' },
    { regex: SyntaxHighlighter.regexLib.doubleQuotedString,    css: 'string' },
    { regex: new RegExp(this.getKeywords(keywords), 'gm'),      css: 'keyword' },
    { regex: new RegExp(this.getKeywords(constants), 'gm'),    css: 'constants' },
    { regex: /[\w._]+[ \t]*(?=\()/gm,               css: 'functions' },
    ];
};
SyntaxHighlighter.brushes.R.prototype  = new SyntaxHighlighter.Highlighter(); SyntaxHighlighter.brushes.R.aliases = ['r', 's', 'splus'];
```

suggested changes to have less highlighting to reply OP's comment:

```
/**
*  Author: Yihui Xie
*  URL: http://yihui.name/en/2010/09/syntaxhighlighter-brush-for-the-r-language
*  License: GPL-2 | GPL-3
*/
SyntaxHighlighter.brushes.R = function() {
    var keywords = 'if else repeat while function for in next break TRUE FALSE NULL Inf NaN NA NA_integer_ NA_real_ NA_complex_ NA_character_';
    var constants = 'LETTERS letters month.abb month.name pi';
    this.regexList = [
    { regex: SyntaxHighlighter.regexLib.singleLinePerlComments, css: 'comments' },
    { regex: new RegExp(this.getKeywords(constants), 'gm'),    css: 'constants' },
    ];
};
SyntaxHighlighter.brushes.R.prototype  = new SyntaxHighlighter.Highlighter(); SyntaxHighlighter.brushes.R.aliases = ['r', 's', 'splus'];
```

Comment: Thanks for the code! I will implement it like that.

Comment: prob too early to select this as an answer. you try it out first and see if it works.